# Javascript: How can I make Synchronous Loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, synchronization

I'm confused by Synchronous/Asynchronous processing of JavaScript.

What I want to do is below. When `self_driving()` is called, then `get_direction_by_sensor()` is called and using the direction, moter starts running by `move_to_direction(direction)`. This process repeats 5 times.

```
function get_direction_by_sensor(){
  // code for getting direction from sensor
  return direction
};

function move_to_direction(direction){
  direction = get_direction_by_sensor()
  // code for driving motor to the direction
};

function self_driving_loop(maxCount, i) {
  if (i <= maxCount) {
    move_to_direction();
    setTimeout(function(){
      self_driving_loop(maxCount, ++i)
    }, 1000);
  }
};

function self_driving() {
  self_driving_loop(5, 1)
};
```

So I want this code to run like this.

```
1. get_direction_by_sensor()
1. move_to_direction()
2. get_direction_by_sensor()
2. move_to_direction()
3. get_direction_by_sensor()
3. move_to_direction()
4. get_direction_by_sensor()
4. move_to_direction()
5. get_direction_by_sensor()
5. move_to_direction()
```

But actually it runs like this.

```
1. get_direction_by_sensor()
2. get_direction_by_sensor()
3. get_direction_by_sensor()
4. get_direction_by_sensor()
5. get_direction_by_sensor() // this direction is used for moving
5. move_to_direction()
```

How can I fix this code?
Thanks.

======== MORE DETAILED INFO ========

`move_to_direction()` calles Macro of webiopi written by Python.

```
function move_to_direction() {
  w().callMacro('get_direction_to_move', [TRIG_F ,ECHO_F ,TRIG_R ,ECHO_R ,TRIG_L ,ECHO_L ,TRIG_B ,ECHO_B], function(macro, args, resp) {
    console.log(resp) // DEBUG
    if(resp == "forward") {
      change_direction('FOWARD');
    } else if(resp == "right") {
      change_direction('RIGHT');
    } else if(resp == "left") {
      change_direction('LEFT');
    } else if(resp == "backward") {
      change_direction('BACKWARD');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I guess you'll need to show a little more about those two functions - must have asynchrony in them, right?

Comment: the code is doing what you want https://repl.it/repls/CostlyBonyApplets

Comment: @Bravo  Yeah, some asynchrony in `move_to_direction` function. What I want to do is finish all the (sub) functions in `move_to_direction` and go to next `move_to_direction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

settimeout must be wrapped with a promise so that it can be awaited. see

```
function self_driving_loop(maxCount, i) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (i <= maxCount) {
       move_to_direction();
       setTimeout(function(){
         self_driving_loop(maxCount, ++i)
         resolve()
       }, 1000);
    }
  })
};
```

call it this way in an **async** function

```
await self_driving_loop(maxCount, i)
```

Comment: did work: `self_driving_loop(maxCount, i)` , didnt work: `await self_driving_loop(maxCount, i)`

Comment: it will work for async function please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function